# Can React Native AsyncStorage use to store data forever?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I want to store app data in AsyncStorage. And I want to persist that data and never get lost when app is going to refresh. Actually I'm going to create a job listing site and I want that user choose cities once whom jobs he wants to see and save that information forever. 
I'm doing like this.

`deviceStorageCity.saveItem("cities", checkedCities);`

```
export const deviceStorageCity = {

  async saveItem(key, value) {
    try {
      var jsonOfItem = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
      return jsonOfItem;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }

};
```

But when I refresh state of that page is also refreshed.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: refer https://pusher.com/tutorials/persisting-data-react-native

Comment: the data will be available until you do not clear it intentionally or clear the app data.